# wav to mp3 encoding using ShineMP3Encoder is really slow on MAC desktop

Tags: macos, actionscript-3, flash, audio

I'm currently using the ShineMP3Encoder from http://github.com/kikko/Shine-MP3-Encoder-on-AS3-Alchemy to convert a recorded wav file to mp3 using flash AS3. The performance is really fast on a windows OS (Any browser) but is really bad (Almost 10 times slower) on a MAC OS (Any browser). 
E.g. A 5 second recording takes nearly 2 mins to be encoded to mp3 on MAC while it only takes about 3 secs on a Windows machine.

I thought I was doing something wrong but I noticed the same problem with the demo at http://code.google.com/p/flash-kikko/

Has anyone faced a similar problem? Are there any alternate MP3 encoders that work well on a MAC desktop?

Comment: I noticed the same issue with iOS. Have you found a workaround?

Comment: I uploaded the raw WAV file to the server and encoded it on there in a background thread. Improved performance that way. Wasn't able to find an encoder that worked well on iOS

Comment: Thanks! I guess this is the best way at this point.